# Need to display Queue inside the Android TextView but need to update it at certain counter interval as the values are FIFO based inside an array

Tags: android

I am actually creating a local score counter app which has to display runs, over as well as it has to showcase a queue of the runs for the last 12 balls as that we usually see in the cricket tournament.

The issue I specifically face is I am using an array for initial 12 values the array showcases the 12 balls designated runs perfectly but after the 12th run I am removing the 0th position array value then when I try to print again in the for loop I get the IndexOutOfBoundsException I totally unsure why.

Here's the code of the function which is facing the issue.

```
TextView runtrain;
int arrayball=0; 
    ArrayList<String> runlist = new ArrayList<String>();    
    public void printRunList() {
                     
                int i=arrayball-1;
        
                runtrain.append(runlist.get(i));
        
                if (arrayball == 12){
                    arrayball--;
                    runlist.remove(0);
                    runtrain.setText("");
                    String inputRun = runtrain.getText().toString();
        
                    for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                        runtrain.append(runlist.get(i));
                    }
                }
        
            }
```

My main motive is to showcase the runs scored on each ball and display it will 12 balls. Once the 13th ball is bowled the 1st ball value is to be removed and 12th position will have the new run. Just like a queue. The issue is with the textview part as it is not updating at the frontend as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue be decreasing the J's value in the for loop.
While debugging the app I noticed at 12 position it throws the IndexOutOfBoundsException. So decreasing the value solved my error.

```
 for(int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
     runtrain.append(runlist.get(i));
   }
```

Thanks for all the help.